# How to show placeholder instead of the state's value at pageload?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to show the placeholder of an input instead of its state value. When I load the page it shows a blank select box, which makes sense because the testType state is null when the page first loads. How can I get it to just show the placeholder instead of the null state?

```js
function RandomSelection(props) {
  const [testType, setTestType] = useState(null);
  const handleTestType = value => {
    setTestType(value);
  };

  return(
  <Select
    placeholder="Test Type..."
    value={testType}
    onChange={handleTestType}
  >
    <Option value="Option 1">
      Option 1
    </Option>
    <Option value="Option 2">Option 2</Option>
    <Option value="Option 3">Option 3</Option>
  </Select>

) }
```

The Select option is from Ant Design, however I feel the solution to this may apply to Material-UI and Bootstrap as well.

Comment: It's working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-3y81g?file=/index.js) unless I'm missing something

Comment: @apokryfos this is a long shot, but maybe the dude uses MUI `Select`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you never show the import path, and your code works perfectly fine using Antd's `Select`, my guess is that you're using the `Select` from MUI (partly because you also tagged [material-ui](/questions/tagged/material-ui) in your question). So check your import path, because MUI `Select` placeholder is set by the `label` prop:

**Right**

```
import { Select } from 'antd';
```

**Wrong**

```
import { Select } from '@mui/material';
```

Comment: I apologize for not providing the import, however I actually am using the ant design Select component. Just decided to include Material-UI as a tag as I thought the Select components from both of these may be similar. Doesn't appear to be an import error, but I appreciate you!

Comment: @personwholikestocode [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773874/how-to-show-placeholder-instead-of-the-states-value-at-pageload/69776050?noredirect=1#comment123334453_69773874) provided a working codesandbox, can you have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

In `const [testType, setTestType] = useState(null);`, set `useState`'s default value to what you want the placeholder to be instead of `null`.

Comment: Thought of using this as well! Just wouldn't want to have the user be able to submit the placeholder text as the value.

Comment: There are a couple different ways to do form validation to prevent that case. Either you could have the validation on the endpoint or in your handleSubmit function.